# Is it the same screwdriver?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Day of the Doctor the War Doctor sets a program running on his screwdriver which 11's then has then completed.

However 10 burnt out his Screwdriver in "Smith and Jones" working on the MRI machine and 11 lost his screwdriver in the "11th Hour"

If that's the case how can the program still be running?

Comment: Pure speculation, hence the comment. Maybe the software on the screwdrivers is backed up to the TARDIS, so each time it's replaced, it gets restored from the remote storage.

Comment: Another speculation, the screw driver may have been repaired rather than replaced at a later point.

Comment: If you're going to run a data analysis program for 1400 years or so, you damn well better do a backup every few years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [TARDIS Data Core Wiki](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Sonic_screwdriver#Variants_of_the_Doctor.27s_sonic_screwdriver) mentions that in the [Eighth Doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eighth_Doctor) novel [**Alien Bodies**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Bodies) in which The Doctor uses his Mark One Sonic Screwdriver which was last seen used by the Second Doctor in Episode 3 of [The War Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_Games) and allegedly destroyed centuries ago from the perspective of the Eighth Doctor.

When his companion [Samantha Jones](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Samantha_Jones) asked how this is possible, he replies:

> It's a Time Lord tool. Time doesn't work the same way for Time Lord tools.

Which suggests that what we saw and interpreted as "destroyed" on-screen isn't really the death of the screwdrivers in question, and they can regenerate or be retrieved from the past somehow.

Answer (score 9):

Day of the Doctor specifically mentions "same software, different case."

The War Doctor puts the calculation in the "software architecture" which is backed up by the Tardis. It doesn't matter if a new Doctor chooses to change the look of the screwdriver, or if the screwdriver gets destroyed, or anything else -- it's the programming behind it that matters.

Answer (score 2):

i think the software being the same and different case in the day of the doctor it refers to is that the sonic software the coding that makes it work is in the TARDIS matrix or data banks and the screwdriver is just a physical way of using it and when it comes to screwdriver dispenser, if you remember the episode with Clara and there's that tree thing that buildings anything you can think of is what he uses to get new screw drivers but